# Search is not working in mui-datatable, reactjs when serverSide is true?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mui-datatable

Hey I have implemented mui-datatable in my project. Everything is working good but the search bar is not working when I am enabling serverSide: true in options.

```
const options = {
    filter: true,
    count: state.count,
    rowsPerPage: state.rowsPerPage,
    serverSide: true,
}
```

If any clarification regarding this problem you want to know please feel free to ask.

Please Help me.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I provide some code so that it will be conceptually clear.

Here I declare some `states` so that we can use these for `paging or data loading`

```
const [data, setData] = useState(carStocks);
const [page, setPage] = useState(0);
const [total, setTotal] = useState(0);
```

Define your method that will call api and set data using `setData`

```
function changePage(newTableState) {
    let state = {
        ...tableState, ...newTableState,
        pageNo: newTableState.page + 1,
        pageSize: newTableState.rowsPerPage,
        searchText: newTableState.searchText
    };
    setTableState(state);
    // CALL API with state parameter
    // setData(data);
    // setPage(page);
    // setTotal(total);
}
```

Here you declare your `columns`

```
const columns = [
   {
        name: 'name',
        label: 'Name',
        options: {
            filter: false,
            sort: false,
            viewColumns: true
        }
    },
    {
        name: 'title',
        label: 'TITLE',
        options: {
            filter: false,
            sort: false,
            viewColumns: true
        }
    },
];
```

Here you declare your `options`. In options you must use `serverSide: true` and if you use `serverSide: true` then you must bind count, page, rowsPerPage with the value based on data size found from api.

```
const options = {
        serverSide: true,
        count: total,
        page: page,
        rowsPerPage: tableState.pageSize,
        selectableRows: 'multiple',
        searchText: tableState.searchText,
        searchPlaceholder: 'Type Car Title to Search',
        textLabels: {
            body: {
                noMatch: loading ?
                    <CircularProgress color='secondary' size={40} /> :
                    'SORRY_THERE_IS_NO_MATCHING_DATA_TO_DISPLAY'
            }
        },
        onTableChange: (action, newTableState) => {
            switch (action) {
                case 'changePage':
                case 'changeRowsPerPage':
                    changePage(newTableState);
                    break;
                case 'search':
                    changePage(newTableState);
                    break;
                case 'filterChange':
                    handleFilterSubmit(newTableState.filterList);
                    break;
            }
        }
    };
```

Finally you can use `data`, `columns` and `options`

```
<MUIDataTable data={data} columns={columns} options={options} />
```

[More Details](https://github.com/gregnb/mui-datatables)

Comment: Why you are you calling changePage function in both cases changeRowsPage and search.

Comment: As you see `changePage` receives `newTableState` as parameter. so you should prepare `newTableState` with all criteria, for example, search word, paging information (pageNo and pageLimit), filtering criteria and so on. So `newTableState` will contain all the inputs and pass it into `changePage`  function.